# Kaplansky's Parallelogram Law - Why is it called like that?

Tags: soft-question, von-neumann-algebras

From Klaplansky's *Rings of Operators*, p.81, the theorem reads as follows:

> For any projections $e$ and $f$ (in a von Neumann algebra), we have $(e \cup f) - f \sim e - e \cap f$.

were $\cap,\cup$ denote the meet and join operations in the lattice of projections and $\sim$ denotes Murray-von Neumann-equivalence.

Why is it called the *parallelogram law*? Kaplansky himself introduces the name before formulating the theorem, but does not motivate it.

This is the motivation I came up with, seeing user218931's answer:
\begin{matrix}
 && e \cup f & \\
&\huge\diagup &  & \huge\diagdown \\
 e & & &  & f\\
&\huge\diagdown &  & \huge\diagup \\
&&e \cap f
\end{matrix}
which is to be unterstand as a diagram in the lattice of projections.

Comment: I just want to comment that this reminds me of the second isomorphism theorem, also called [the diamond/parallelogram rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Second_isomorphism_theorem).  A nice graph can be seen [in the graph of this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1738623/32803).

Comment: @FrenzyLi: Interesting observation. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
Just draw a picture
$$
\begin{CD}
e\cup f @>>> e\\
@VVV @VVV\\
f @>>> e\cap f
\end{CD}
$$
(but without the arrow tips). Then $e\cup f - f \sim e - e\cap f$ can be interpreted as “the lengths of the sides $e\cup f$ to $f$ and $e$ to $e\cap f$ are equal”. Symmetrically $e\cup f - e \sim f - e\cap f$ is interpreted as “the lengths of the sides $e\cup f$ to $e$ and $f$ to $e\cap f$ are equal”. So geometrically, this resembles a parallelogram.

Comment: why without the arrow tips? If arrows point from "larger" to "smaller" elements in the lattice, your diagram makes sense. I have updated my original post with a new version of your diagram.

Comment: The arrow tips do not contribute anything to the parallelogram image. But given your interpretation, they kind of make sense.